# How to set form action in Symfony2? (2.8 LTS)

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

So I've been playing around with Symfony forms and I want to change the form action.

I've followed this [guide](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-method-of-a-form) but I don't understand what it means by "target_route". As such, I was getting an error message (see below)

I have the code below and I'm pretty sure the route I used in setAction is valid since I can browse it using my browser.

Any ideas? Thank you

my code:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/DirectoryController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DirectoryController extends Controller {
    /**
    * @Route("/directory/form")
    */
    public function formAction() {
        $form = $this->get("form.factory")
            ->createNamedBuilder("form", "form")
                ->setAction($this->generateUrl("/directory/search"))
                ->setMethod("get")
                ->add("search", "submit", array("label" => "Search"))
                ->add("reset", "reset", array("label" => "Reset"))
                ->getForm();

        return $this->render(
            "directory/form.html.twig",
                array("form" => $form->createView()
                    ,
                )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/directory/search")
     */
    public function searchAction() {

        return $this->render(
                "directory/view.html.twig"
                );
    }
}
```

**error message:**

```
 Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/directory/search" as such route does not exist.
```

Comment: [psst](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315556/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example, `target_route` is the name of a route, not its url. For example, you might define an action like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/directory/search", name="directory_search")
 */
public function searchAction() {
```

In that case, your route would have a name of `directory_search`. You would then use `$this->generateUrl('directory_search')` to have the router turn the name into a url.

The reason you do it this way (as opposed to using urls directly) is that this allows you to change a url without having to change *every* place in your code that references it.

> ```
> ->setAction($this->generateUrl("/directory/search"))
> ```

`setAction()` expects a url. So you while you *can* give it `'/directory/search'`, best practice would be to it `$this->generateUrl('directory_search')`.